# 1 field have multiple values in solr how to define.?

Tags: tomcat, solr, solrnet

I want to store product specification attirbutes in solr.but how i don't know?
for example 1 product have scree-size , weight , colour etc 
and other product have only weight , ram , memory 
so how i can make schema.xml for store this.

please give me idea or hint.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define them all in the schema, without setting them as 'required' fields.